# TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed

Tags: python, python-3.x, url, python-requests, urllib

> TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

I did everything I can think of to fix this but maybe im not fully understanding this error. Please help me out.

Here is the code and link.

```py
import urllib.request
import requests

link = "https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?symbolCode=242&symbol=RELIANCE&symbol=RELIANCE&instrument=OPTSTK&date=-segmentLink=17&segmentLink=17"


user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'
request = urllib.request.Request(link,headers={'User-Agent': user_agent})
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
html = response.read()
print(html)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) instead:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()) + "/chromedriver")
link = "https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?symbolCode=242&symbol=RELIANCE&symbol=RELIANCE&instrument=OPTSTK&date=-&segmentLink=17&segmentLink=17"
browser.get(link)
context = browser.page_source
```

Comment: I want to scrap the table given at the website for 1000s of stocks so its not practical to open chrome 1000s time to scrap the table. So I am trying to scrap it without selenium. Is there any other way?